# Computing annihilator of a subset of a given vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, dual-spaces

My question is to determine the annihilator of the subset $$S=\{(x, y, z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : xy = 1\}$$ 
of vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$.

> Annihilator of a subset of a vector space can be stated as follows:
>
> Annihilator of a subset $S$ of a vector space $V$ over a field $F$ is
>   the subset $S^0$ of the dual space $V^*$given by $S^0 = \{f\in
>  V^\star:f(\alpha)=0~~   \forall \alpha \in S\}$.

I fail to apply this definition to solve above stated problem. How to randomly search for such kind of functional. What should be a general approach to deal solve such kind of problem? I need help with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\alpha\in S^0$, then $\alpha(1,1,1)=\alpha\left(2,\frac12,0\right)=\alpha\left(\frac12,2,0\right)=0$. Since $\left\{(1,1,1),\left(2,\frac12,0\right)\left(\frac12,2,0\right)\right\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb R^3$, $\alpha=0$. So, $S^0=\{0\}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why annihilator would be zero functional if those vectors form basis?

Comment: Because, given a basis $B$ of a vector space $V$ and a linear map $f$ from $V$ into another vector space $W$, $f$ is the null function if and only if$$(\forall v\in B):f(v)=0.$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood completely.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.